# Assignment of unreferenced variables?

Tags: c

I saw the following code in the wild and I don't know what to make of it:

more or less:

```
int main(void)
{
   int a = 0, v;
   printf("%d\n", v); 
}
```

This code with gcc will print out 0. At first I though, oh well that's because initialized local variables are assigned 0, but in this case I never declared the type of v...so what gives?

Comment: *initialized local variables are assigned 0* - No, it have garbage. And the type of `v` is `int`.

Comment: The type of v is `int`. And the behavior is still undefined. `v`'s value is [*indeterminate*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17394924/1322972).

Comment: On my machine I get 1664045150 and not 0.  You just happened to get 0.

Comment: FWIW I think a better title for this question would be "Value of unassigned local variables" because as it stands your program does not have any assignment to `v` nor can you call `v` unreferenced, because you ... clearly referenced it!  #Pedantic :)

Comment: Reading an uninitialized variable results in undefined behavior.

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian Instead of guessing, I recommend that you read over the basics of C more carefully first.  The answers are helpful too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int a = 0, v;
```

is equivalent to:

```
int a = 0;
int v;
```

So you *did* declare the type of `v`, just not explicitly.  It's an `int`.

Anyway, [like all uninitialized local variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597405/what-happens-to-a-declared-uninitialized-variable-in-c-does-it-have-a-value), `v`'s value isn't guaranteed to be anything.  Accessing it is still undefined behavior; you just happened to get 0.

Answer (score 1):

What do you think the comma does in a declaration statement?

In C - C99 and C++, an initializer is an optional part of a declarator. The [init-declarator-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15250318/init-declarator-list-and-the-gnu-gcc-attribute-grammar) is a comma-separated sequence of declarators, each of which can have additional type information, or an initializer, or both.

As such, your expression `int a = 0, v;` does declare `v` as a an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Type of `v` is `int`. Please read the syntax of variable declaration.

You are just lucky that it is printing 0. Value of `v` is garbage.

Answer (score 1):

From **ISO/IEC 9899:TC2** *section 6.7.8 Semantics*

If an object that has `automatic storage duration` is not initialized explicitly, `its value is indeterminate`. 
If an object that has static storage duration is not initialized explicitly,
then:
— if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
— if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;
— if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules;
— if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these
rules.

Answer (score 0):

[From Wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Variables),

Multiple variables can be declared with one statement, like this:

```
int anumber, anothernumber, yetanothernumber;
```